# efficient way to calculate between columns with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looks  like

```
            Cnt_A  Cnt_B  Cnt_C  Cnt_D
ID_1          0      1      3      0
ID_2          1      0      0      0 
ID_3          5      2      0      8  
...
```

I'd like to count columns that are not zero and put the result into new column like this,

```
          Total_Not_Zero_Cols   Cnt_A  Cnt_B  Cnt_C  Cnt_D
ID_1               2              0      1      3      0
ID_2               1              1      0      0      0 
ID_3               3              5      2      0      8  
...
```

I did loop to get the result, but it took very long time (of course).

I can't figure out the most efficient way to calculate between columns with condition :(

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if each value not equals to 0 then sum on columns axis:

```py
df['Total_Not_Zero_Cols'] = df.ne(0).sum(axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
      Cnt_A  Cnt_B  Cnt_C  Cnt_D  Total_Not_Zero_Cols
ID_1      0      1      3      0                    2
ID_2      1      0      0      0                    3
ID_3      5      2      0      8                    1
```

Comment: Or maybe `.ne(0)`?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) to generate a DataFrame of booleans with True for non-zeros values, then aggregate the rows as integers using [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```py
df['Total_Not_Zero_Cols'] = df.ne(0).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Numpy based -

Use -

```
np.sum(df!=0, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
ID_1    2
ID_2    1
ID_3    3
dtype: int64
```